# Change of variable on uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

I want to proof that, if $x_{i}$ (independent) with i $\in$[0,12] follow a uniform distribution, then $z=\sum_{i=1}^{12}x_{i}-6$ follow a normal distribution. I started by writting:

$g(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{1}f(x_{1})...\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{12}f(x_{12})\delta(\sum_{i=1}^{12}x_{i}-6-z)$

$f(x_{i})$ are the uniform distributions.

I want to do a change variable so that $x_{i} \rightarrow y_{i}/N$ (with $N=12$) with $y_{i}$ my new variable. The reason I want to do this is to have a similar expression as in the Central Limit Theorem. The problem is that I don't know how this affects the uniform distribution.

$g(z) = \frac{1}{N^{N}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy_{1}f(y_{1}/N)...\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy_{12}f(y_{12}/N)\delta(\sum_{i=1}^{12}(x_{i}/N)-6-z)$

$f(y_{i}/N)$ is not anymore the uniform distribution as it is not properly normalized, but I don't know what the correct normalization would be now. Should I introduce a 1/N factor inside each $f(y_{i}/N)$ so that way it is normalized correctly? And why is 1/N the correct normalization?

Thanks.

Comment: uniform distribution... on what?

Comment: @Exodd I don't understand the question

Comment: @Exodd if  you want to know the limits of the uniform distribution, it is a standard one, i.e, from [0,1]

Comment: If $x_i$ are on $[0,1]$, then $z$ is on $[-6,6]$. How can it be a normal variable?

Comment: z will not be normal as a sum of independent identically distributed uniform variables. Did you mean approximately normal?

Answer (score 1):

$z$ is not going to follow a normal distribution - for a start, a normal distribution can take any real number as a result, but $z$ is going to be restricted to a finite interval since it's the sum of finitely many bounded uniform distributions.

However, by the Central Limit Theorem, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ you will find that $\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$ will approach a normal distribution with mean $\frac{1}{2}$. So even $z$, which comes from summing 6 such variables, will look approximately normal, especially close to the centre of its distribution.